# NUnit fail with System.ArgumentException: The net-4.0 framework is not available

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5, nunit-console

**Exception:**
ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-4.0
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentException: The net-4.0 framework is not available
Parameter name: framework
   at NUnit.Util.TestAgency.GetAgent(RuntimeFramework framework, Int32 waitTime, Boolean enableDebug)
   at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.ConsoleUi.Execute(ConsoleOptions options)
   at NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(String[] args)

**OS**
Winserver 2008 R2 x64

**Nunit**
2.5.4.10098

**Test assembly**
Built for .net 4.0 RTM (v4.0.30319)

**Commandline**
nunit-console.exe NServiceBus.Config.UnitTests.dll /framework=net-4.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Combine Kev's advice ( add /framework=4.0.30319 to the parameter list)
and modify nunit-console.exe.config  with the following:

under

```
 <configuration>
```

add:

```
<startup>  <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /></startup>
```

under `<configuration><runtime>`  add:

```
 <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
```

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Had to add:
 <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />
to the runtime section as well though!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with CC.net.

I now run NUnit from NAnt using the arguement /framework=4.0.30319

Hope this helps

Kev

Comment: Thanks, that got me further but now I get this error instead:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   [exec]    at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   [exec]    at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   [exec]    at NUnit.Util.RemoteTestAgent.AgentRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   [exec]    at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Ob
ct server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
Full dump here: http://pastie.org/919114